# Silverlight Toolkit not available after the installation of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, I customized my installation(I stripped-down C++,J# because I didn't need it)..After the installation the SilverLight did not appear in the installed templates. Do I have to install SilverLight tools separately? Doesn't the VS 2010 Ultimate come bundled with silverlight tools?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some option during customize installation, its come with Visual Studio 2010.

You can install separately silverlight tools also.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've missed something, I don't remember excluding silverlight toolkit during the installation. But my customized installation was successful.

Did you installed service pack 1 update for visual studio? If you didn't I would recommend you to check for Windows Updates.

In any case you can download the tools you need or for silverlight a clean install from [here (silverlight get started)](http://www.silverlight.net/downloads) but the tools you need are the [Silverlight 5 RC Tools for Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27220)